# Where to find an actual bigdata with Variety and Volume?

Tags: big-data

I am exploring the field of BigData analytics. I am basically interested in dealing with two V's: Volume and Variety. I am not able to find a decent data which has a Volume enough to be called a big data along with the Variety in the same dataset consisting of images and text both. I have tried searching on various websites where we usually search for datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pretty vague question, but one data source with variety of data would be the Twitter feed. The data can grow as "voluminous" as you want, and you can use the data in a "variety" of ways. For example:

1. volume - download billions of tweets
2. variety - use the various types of data that comes with social networks.

   - Graph/network machine learning on the links between accounts or the biological-like spread of retweets.
   - Image analysis on what images/figs are shared, or profile images
   - Text mining on the actual tweet text, such as sentiment analysis
   - Geographical analysis with geo-tagged tweets
   - [etc](https://chatbotslife.com/twitter-data-mining-a-guide-to-big-data-analytics-using-python-4efc8ccfa219)

Here's an [overview](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/intro-to-tweet-json) of what data and metadata comes with a tweet.

Search through [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=twitter) and others about Twitter datasets and API access. If you have a specific question that isn't a duplicate, feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can find large public datasets in sources including Google Open Data, Kaggle Datasets, Github and Data.gov. If you are specifically looking for large data coverage, the California Open Data Portal- CA.gov is a great resource. It includes government data and a broad collection of topics.

Comment: Main problem is finding large data with variety.

Comment: @People Data Labs: he is asking for big data, not for open data; open data are not necessary big